# Jackson serialize Joda DateTime from simple String

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to extract a value of predefined type (Boolean, Integer, joda.DateTime) from an arbitrary json that is sent as a String.
Eg: `{"node1":{"node2":"2019-01-01T05:00:00.000Z"}}}` and say I know that the value in this Json is a DateTime and I can extract the value `2019-01-01T05:00:00.000Z` from this Json and disabled `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`.

When I try to serialize a simple String representation "1972-12-28T12:00:01.000Z" of org.joda.time.DateTime, it fails with `JsonParseException: Unexpected character`. However serialization will succeed for Booleans or DateTime string inside a TextNode.

I have have registered com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule with my object mapper.

I have tried a few things, see the Junit test below

```java
public class Tester {

    public static class Bean {
        public void Bean(){}
        public DateTime start;
    }

    @Test
    public void testJodaJsonSerialization() throws Exception{

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());

        final String INPUT_JSON = "{\"start\" : \"1972-12-28T12:00:01.000Z\"}";
        Bean bean = objectMapper.readValue(INPUT_JSON, Bean.class);
        assertNotNull(bean.start);
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(bean)); //serializing as part of an object works

        String boolAsString = "true";
        Boolean aBoolean = objectMapper.readValue(boolAsString, Boolean.class); //works for bool (simple type)

        System.out.println(aBoolean);
        String dateAsTextNode = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new TextNode("1972-12-28T12:00:01.000Z")); //works for TextNode
        System.out.println("dateAsTextNode: " + dateAsTextNode);
        DateTime dateTime = objectMapper.readValue(dateAsTextNode, DateTime.class);
        System.out.println(dateTime);


        JsonNode jsonRoot = objectMapper.readTree(INPUT_JSON);
        String datetimeAsString = jsonRoot.get("start").asText();
        objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new TextNode(datetimeAsString)), DateTime.class); //this workaround will work
        objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new TextNode(boolAsString)), Boolean.class);

        String dateAsString = "1972-12-28T12:00:01.000Z";
        objectMapper.readValue(dateAsString, DateTime.class); //but this fails
    }
}
```

I expect String serialization to work just like it does on the TextNode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `String`

```
String dateAsString = "1972-12-28T12:00:01.000Z";
```

contains the content

```
1972-12-28T12:00:01.000Z
```

which is not valid JSON, so Jackson cannot parse it.

It would be valid JSON if it contained leading quotes, so

```java
String dateAsString = "\"1972-12-28T12:00:01.000Z\"";
```

and then parsing would succeed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Yes, in the quotes it is a valid "string json literal". Boolean was a valid json literal because {"node1":true} is a valid json without any quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the pattern of the date format on the ObjectMapper level:

```
Value dateFormat = Value.forShape(Shape.STRING)
    .withPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    .withTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
    .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
    .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
    .configOverride(DateTime.class).setFormat(dateFormat);
```